# Drag'n'drop taglist elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need your help.
I'm trying to create a droppable taglist like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FawRi.png)

List elements (Parametr 1, Parametr 2, Parametr 3) are draggable and the field above called 'Tekst naglowka' is droppable. I need the tags to look like this on inclosed image ('Parametr 1' with 'cross' at the end).

Do you have any ideas?

There is my js:

```
$('ul li').draggable({
revert: true,
helper: 'clone',
revert: "invalid",
cursor: "move"
});

initDroppable($("#headerTextInput"));

function initDroppable($elements) {
$elements.droppable({
  activeClass: "ui-state-default",
  hoverClass: "ui-drop-hover",
  accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
  over: function(event, ui) {
    var $this = $(this);
  },
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $("#headerTextInput p").remove();
    $("#headerTextInput").focus();
    $("<div class='dropped'></div>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);
    $(".dropped").append("<i class='droppedCross fa fa-times' aria-hidden='true'></i>");
    if (this.children.length > 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
});}

$("#headerTextInput").sortable();
```

And my html:

```
    <label class="headerTextLabel" for="headerTextInput">Tekst nagłówka</label>
    <div id="headerTextInput" tabindex="0"><p>Dodaj tekst...</p></div>

    <div class="addParameterButton">
      DODAJ PARAMETR
    </div>

    <ul class="parametersList">
      <li id="Parameter 1" class="listElement">Parametr 1</li><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <li id="Parameter 2" class="listElement">Parametr 2</li><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <li id="Parameter 3" class="listElement">Parametr 3</li><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </ul>
```

What can I do to make tags look like example enclosed? I mean - with the cross at the end of tag after each drop?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
$('ul li').draggable({
  revert: true,
  helper: 'clone',
  revert: "invalid",
  cursor: "move"
});

initDroppable($("#headerTextInput"));

function initDroppable($elements) {
  $elements.droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-drop-hover",
    accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
    over: function(event, ui) {
      var $this = $(this);
    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var $this = $(this);
      $("#headerTextInput p").remove();
      $("#headerTextInput").focus();
      $("<div class='dropped'></div>").html(ui.draggable.text()+"<i class='droppedCross fa fa-times' aria-hidden='true'></i>").appendTo(this);
      
      if (this.children.length > 0) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
}

$("#headerTextInput").sortable();
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<label class="headerTextLabel" for="headerTextInput">Tekst nagłówka</label>
<div id="headerTextInput" tabindex="0">
  <p>Dodaj tekst...</p>
</div>

<div class="addParameterButton">
  DODAJ PARAMETR
</div>

<ul class="parametersList">
  <li id="Parameter 1" class="listElement">Parametr 1</li><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <li id="Parameter 2" class="listElement">Parametr 2</li><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <li id="Parameter 3" class="listElement">Parametr 3</li><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</ul>
```

Use `.html()` instead of `.text()` and just append with it the font-awesome icon.

Comment: Great! :) Thank you sooooo much! :)

Comment: @JanKowalski Glad I was able to help. Just mark this as the answer.. You can see at the left side of my answer..